# Division In Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, group-by

This is sample information from my database so full picture can be shown as to what I am needing to accomplish

```
Create Table #Information
(
    salesID int,
    storelocation varchar(100),
    salespersonName varchar(100)
)

Insert Into #Information Values
(1, 'New York', 'Michael'),
(2, 'New York', 'Michael'),
(3, 'New York', 'Michael'),
(4, 'New York', 'Michael'),
(5, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(6, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(7, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(8, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(9, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(10, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(11, 'Washington', 'Sam'),
(12, 'Washington', 'Sam'),
(13, 'Washington', 'Sam'),
(14, 'Washington', 'Sam'),
(15, 'Washington', 'Sam')


SELECT storelocation,
COUNT(salesID/storelocation)
FROM #Information
```

I want to get a count of Total count of salesID then divide by the salesID for that storelocation.  So the division I want to happen would be

```
New York - 15/4 = .266
Texas - 15/6 = .4
Washington - 15/5 = .333
```

The way I have been doing this is like so - but this is not returning accurate results.

```
declare @TotalCount as int
select @TotalCount = convert(decimal(18,4), count(salesID))
from #information
Select
convert(decimal(18,4), Count(salesID))/@TotalCount
From #information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the total Count query as `Subquery` and divide it by `storelocation` group count

```
SELECT storelocation,
       (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 4), Count(1))
        FROM   #Information) / Count(1)
FROM   #Information
GROUP  BY storelocation
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #Information
(
    salesID             INT,
    storelocation       VARCHAR(100),
    salespersonName     VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Information
VALUES
(1, 'New York', 'Michael'),
(2, 'New York', 'Michael'),
(3, 'New York', 'Michael'),
(4, 'New York', 'Michael'),
(5, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(6, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(7, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(8, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(9, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(10, 'Texas', 'Richard'),
(11, 'Washington', 'Sam'),
(12, 'Washington', 'Sam'),
(13, 'Washington', 'Sam'),
(14, 'Washington', 'Sam'),
(15, 'Washington', 'Sam')


DECLARE @TotalCount AS INT
SELECT @TotalCount = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 4), COUNT(salesID))
FROM   #information

SELECT storelocation,
       @TotalCount / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 4), COUNT(storelocation)) AS Division
FROM   #Information
GROUP BY
       storelocation
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TotalCount as int;

SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(salesID) 
FROM #information;

SELECT storeLocation, (@TotalCount / COUNT(salesID)) AS division
FROM #information
GROUP BY storeLocation;
```